# What is the proper name of this fan connector?

Tags: identification, connector, fan, pc

Does anybody know what the correct name for this fan connector is?

The female plug side is "Molex KK 254 Housing with Polarization Rib, 4 pin" https://molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/470541000

Looking for the circled male/socket version's name.

The board header version of this is the "KK 254 Vertical Header, with Friction Lock, 4 Circuits" https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/470531000, but I'm looking for the version where you can crimp wires onto contacts, and insert them into a plug body.

[image: PC Fan extender cable sockets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for (not a Molex product):

https://www.moddiy.com/products/modDIY-Male-4-Pin-PWM-Fan-Connector-Molex-2510.html

This item here is a Molex product and appears to be just that little bit closer to what you are looking for:

https://au.element14.com/molex/29-11-0043/connector-housing-plug-4pos-2/dp/3049990

I found a similar question being asked on another forum about three years ago, the connector pictured looks to be the same type:

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/j7xur7/connector_help_molex_kk_254_4pin_male_crimp/?rdt=57174

Comment: This sounds like the answer.  You might add some quoted content for posterity; the note that it's specifically not a Molex part seems particularly important. For my part, I don't see any other mating parts from the manufacturer themselves, which, short of catalogging errors (which can happen, but I don't have any particular reason to suspect Molex of being lazy/inaccurate in this case?), indicates it simply isn't theirs.

Comment: Hmm, 2.5mm pitch would be pretty tight for 4 pins. The tab doesn't line up I think: 5.34mm is the gap to fit, but the 4-pin part has a 7.5mm tab.

Comment: I still haven’t found the correct name for it, but I did find some suppliers that aren’t Amazon or eBay through that Reddit post. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Also looking into it more, it doesn’t look like a true Molex connector, but something that fits the KK 254 female plug.  Also I think the one part you linked with the two tabs may not fit well, but I would have to order one to test that out. For now I’m going to get this: https://mainframecustom.com/shop/cable-sleeving/connectors/4pin-fan-male-connector/